# html table breaks when too much text into cells and doesnt look ood on print

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

So I have this school project where I have to create an html/css file mostly tables that look good when printed on an A4 sheet,the problem is some of the cell blocks contain over 40 characters, which messe the whole table up, what is the solution to that, perhaps make the printer print two a4 sheets, but I have no clue how to do that.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif
}

img {
  width: 20%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
}

* {
  font-weight: lighter;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

th {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.padding {
  padding-right: 82px;
}

tr {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #2C5197;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.num {
  border: none;
}

.border2 {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
}

.border3 {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.border3 td {
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-right: 1.5px solid black;
}

.border2 td {
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-right: 1.5px solid black;
}

.border td {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-right: 1.5x solid black;
}

.border td {
  border: none;
}

.border {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}

.border td {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-right: 1.5px solid black;
}

.border1 td {
  border: none;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
  border-right: 1.5px solid black;
}

.border1 {
  border: none;
  border-right: 1.5px solid black;
  border-left: 1.5px solid black;
}

.border5 {
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.border5 td {
  border-top: none;
}

p {
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.secondtable {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.secondtable table {
  width: 50.3%;
}

.secondtable tbody td {
  text-align: center;
}

@page {
  size: A4 portrait;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="header">
    <h1>Measurement Report</h1>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/yFs5jxq/logo.png" alt="engineering quality">
  </div>


  <h2>Configuration</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>Device: 11-abcd-sp</li>
    <li>Start of Measurement: 18.08.2021 10:51</li>
    <li>End of Measurement: 18.08.2021 10:51</li>
    <li> Measurement Type: Meter Test</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Tested Networks</h2>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Provider</th>
        <th>T-Mobile DE</th>
        <th>T-Mobile DE</th>
        <th class='padding'>...</th>
        <th class='padding'></th>
        <th class='padding'></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Technology</td>
        <td>GSM</td>
        <td>LTE</td>
        <td class='padding'></td>
        <td class='padding'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border1">
        <td>Band(s)</td>
        <td>900</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border">
        <td></td>
        <td class="num">1800</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border2">
        <td class="num"></td>
        <td class="num"></td>
        <td class="num">3</td>
        <td class="num"></td>
        <td class="num"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border3">
        <td class="num"></td>
        <td class="num"></td>
        <td class="num">4</td>
        <td class="num"></td>
        <td class="num"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="border5">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <p>dog</p>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="secondtable">
    <h2>Measurement Data</h2>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Provider</th>
          <th>Technology</th>
          <th>RSSI</th>
          <th>RSRP</th>
          <th>RSRQ</th>
          <th>Band</th>
          <th>Cell ID</th>
          <th>LAC</th>
          <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>01.09.2021 09:43:13</td>
          <td>T-Mobile (Germany)</td>
          <td>4G</td>
          <td>-80dBm</td>
          <td>-2347dBm</td>
          <td>-1000dBm</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>21.12.2021 13:23:04</td>
          <td>Vodafone (Spain)</td>
          <td>5G</td>
          <td>-20dBm</td>
          <td>-1000dBm</td>
          <td>-80dBm</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quam quibusdam, veritatis deleniti eaque necessitatibus et a numquam quis reprehenderit nesciunt accusantium quisquam alias dolore distinctio repudiandae similique molestiae architecto!
            Totam beatae consequuntur, nulla debitis sed placeat voluptate tempora corporis ducimus.</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>14.10.2021 16:00:12</td>
          <td>T-Mobile (America)</td>
          <td>4G</td>
          <td>-1000dBm</td>
          <td>-20dBm</td>
          <td>-20dBm</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>13.01.2021 12:23:02</td>
          <td>T-Mobile (Italy)</td>
          <td>2G</td>
          <td>-2345dBm</td>
          <td>-80dBm</td>
          <td>-2345dBm</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
          <td>blank</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what you can do in that situation other than cut off a lot of the text

Answer (score 0):

Can you print it horizontally? If you can print the table with 90 degree rotation then you can increase the width of table cell which contains more than 40 words.

From horizontally , I mean print the table in landscape and you will have more space to fit your contents.